# How many 7-digit ID numbers do not contain three consecutive sixes.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a homework question in a discrete mathematics class that asks me to determine how many 7-digit id numbers **do not** contain three consecutive sixes.

It seems clear that I should approach this by determining the number that **do** have three consecutive sixes and subtracting that from $10^7$, the total number of possibilities.

If it were asking simply for the number of values that contain three sixes, it would simply be $10^4$, or $9^4$ for *exactly* three sixes. But what's got me thinking is the requirement that they appear consecutively. By sketching out this:

```
___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___ 
 x    x    x                           1
      x    x    x                      2
           x    x    x                 3
                x    x    x            4
                     x    x    x       5
```

I determined that there are five possible placements, so I'm thinking that the number of values with three consecutive sixes is $5 * 10^4$. But because arrangements 1&4, 1&5 and 2&5 can coincide, this overcounts by $3 *10 = 30$, so I get a final total of $5 * 10^4 - 30$ values with three consecutive sixes.

Questions:

- Is my basic approach here logically sound?
- Making that sketch felt awfully "hacky" - is there a mathematical technique I could have used instead - particularly when I'm dealing with bigger values?

Comment: first of all, the integers with 7 digit aren't $10^7$

Comment: @Exodd whoops, corrected. Thanks

Comment: Consecutive 6es or 0es?

Comment: @Tim: sixes, sorry, that was a mess

Comment: My computer just told me there are 1771012 numbers with 3 consecutive 6es!

Comment: @Tim - so where is my logic failing me?

Comment: $7^{10}$ is 282,475,249 not 9,999,999. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started out just fine by counting the following kinds of numbers:

```
___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___ 
 6    6    6                           1
      6    6    6                      2
           6    6    6                 3
                6    6    6            4
                     6    6    6       5
```

And you’re right that you have to adjust for overcounting. Think of it this way, you’ve counted the numbers in the set $S_1$ of numbers $666????$, $S_2$ of numbers $?666???$, and so on. There are $10,000$ in each set. (Let’s assume ID numbers can begin with the digit $0$.)

Some numbers, however, are in more than one set. There are two kinds of these numbers: the numbers with $4$ or more consecutive sixes and the numbers with two separated groups of consecutive sixes. Let’s use X to mean a non-6 digit and count, beginning with those that have $4$, but not $5$, consecutive sixes.

Numbers of the form $6666X??$ are in $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Numbers of the form $X6666X?$ are in $S_2$ and $S_3$.

Numbers of the form $?X6666X$ are in $S_3$ and $S_4$.

Numbers of the form $??X6666$ are in $S_4$ and $S_5$.

There are 900+810+810+900 of these, and they were counted twice, so we need to subtract $3,420$ from your initial count of $50,000$. Now those with $5$, but not $6$ consecutive sixes. (We haven't considered them in the previous calculation.)

Numbers like $66666X?$, $X66666X$, and $?X66666$. Each was counted three times, and there are $90+81+90=261$ of them. So subtract another $522$.

Next, numbers like $X666666$ and $666666X$ were counted four times, and there are $9+9$ of those, so subtract another $3\cdot18$, and $6666666$ was counted five times, so subtract $4$.

Two separated $666$s occur in numbers like $666X666$ and were counted twice, so subtract $9$.

Summarizing, there are $50,000-3,420-522-54-4-9=45,591$ numbers containing $666$, leaving $9,954,009$ 7-digit numbers (possibly starting with one or more zeros) with no string of three sixes.

The mathematical principle (search and you'll find a general way to solve these problems) is called "inclusion-exclusion." Your initial approach is just what you need to get started with it.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for being so thorough!

Answer (score 0):

This short python script:

```
for i in range (10**6,(10**7)-1):
    if '666' in str(i):
        x += 1
```

spat out an answer of 42291 at the end!

It works by getting every number from 0 to $7^{10}$ (282475249), not 0 to 9,999,999. I am not sure which you are looking for. This may be your problem.

8999999 - 42291 = 8957708

Comment: It should be "for i in range(10**6, 10**7-1)" and it gives me 42291 as the answer

Comment: @Yaitzme Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see it as a sequence of X numbers different than 6 where you put between them, or in the final of the string, a group of six of any cardinality between 0 and 2.

At maximum, because digit length is 7, you can have a string of 7 different numbers with gaps/ends with cardinality 0.

For any gap with cardinality 1 the length decreases by one, and for any gap with cardinality 2 the length decreases by two.

The different combinations of gaps for a length *l* will be

- $l=7\to 0/8$
- $l=6\to 1/7$
- $l=5\to 2/6$
- $l=4\to 3/5$
- $l=3\to 4/4$
- $l=2\to 5/3$
- $l=1\to 6/2$
- $l=0\to 7/1$

The expression $a/b$ means partition $a$ quantity on $b$ parts. More than partition they are partitions where order cares and you can have positions with zeroes and an upper bound of cardinality $2$.

These type of bounded distributions can be computed trough a generating function like this

$$f(x)=(1+x+x^2)^{l+1}=\left(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^{l+1}=\sum_{h=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{h}(-1)^hx^{3h}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{l+j}{l}x^j$$

Now we have that $3h+j=7-l \to j=7-l-3h$, and the permutations for some *l* will be

$$p(l)=\sum_{h=0}^{l+1}(-1)^h\binom{l+1}{h}\binom{7-3h}{l}$$

But we must notice that when $7-3h<l$ the sum is zero, so $7-3h\geq l \to h\leq\frac{7-l}{3}$. So the sum will be

$$p(l)=\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\frac{7-l}{3}\rfloor}(-1)^h\binom{l+1}{h}\binom{7-3h}{l}$$

And for every *l* the base amount of permutations will be $PB(l)=9^l$. And because the probability to the string start with a zero is $\frac{1}{10}$ then the final formula will be

$$P=\frac{9}{10}\sum_{l=0}^{7}9^l\sum_{h=0}^{\lfloor\frac{7-l}{3}\rfloor}(-1)^h\binom{l+1}{h}\binom{7-3h}{l}$$

P.S.: Im not completely sure about the probability of $\frac{1}{10}$ of start with zero for this problem. If someone can confirm or negate it I will appreciate it a lot. Maybe more safe try the **negative** approach, i.e., evaluate the string with 3 or more 6's and after subtract to the total. Anyway isnt clear the amount of strings starting with zero from one or other approach.